# Two DataSources In DataGrid

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a problem when I bind a datasource to gridview

I have a table with this fields: `Name, Family, cityId`
And another table with this field: cited, cityName`

I want to show this column in gridview: `Name, Family, cityName`

But I can't.. When I want to bind dataSource to gridview, I can see only table one's columns.

And my command is:

```
select * from table1, table2
```

I don't like to change my command in the datasource.

Can anybody help me?
Thanks...

Comment: you can create a view from those two table and then bind that view to grid

Comment: Did you added the column names(Name, Family, cityName) in the gridview

Comment: yes I add this columns name in gridview but I dont know how to fix the data property for CityName...

Comment: Could you show your code which defines a datasource and a gridview and a code that binds this datasource to the gridview?

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a view or another sql statement to solve this. Solve this client side is not possible as far as I know.

**Option 1: create this in the database:**

```
create view FamilyWithCity
as
select t1.Name, t1.Family, t2.CityName
from   table1 t1
,      table2 t2
where  t1.CityId = t2.CityId
```

And call this in c#:

```
select * from FamilyWithCity
```

**Option 2: Put this in your c# code:**

```
select t1.Name, t1.Family, t2.CityName
from   table1 t1
,      table2 t2
where  t1.CityId = t2.CityId
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I dont have permission to change data source from employer!! Do you mean I change the data source to that?

Comment: You have to either change it client side or server side. If you can't change the database, use Option 2.

Comment: @Elahe: Do you need more help? If not, please close this question by marking it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set several datasources on any control.

Why not create a stored procedure that retrieves all the information you want in one go? Then you can bind the result to your DataGrid.

Try this as DataSource

```
SELECT T1.Name, T1.Family, T2.CityName
From   table1 T1 Left Join table2 T2 ON T2.CityID = T1.CityID
```